# How to use vga passthrough in Ubuntu 15.10 with two AMD graphic cards using the same driver

Tags: linux, drivers, amd-radeon, kvm-switch, ubuntu-15.10

I have a **Ubuntu 15.10** based PC with **two different ATI/AMD graphics cards** (ATI Radeon 4650 and AMD 7970) I want to install Windows via qemu/kvm with **vga passthrough**. For this I have to blacklist the AMD 7970 card using the command **blacklist radeon**. Unfortnately the radeon driver ist used for both cards, so I am afraid of blacklisting both cards. What coudl I do to circumvent this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to let EITHER `vfio-pci` OR `pci-stub` (depends on whether you use the newer `-device vfio-pci` or older `-device pci-assign`) bind the card for passthrough first.

Depends on whether you load either of the modules and/or radeon in the initramfs, you might need to use a `softdep` in /etc/modprobe.d to make sure `radeon` is loaded later than the passthrough module. (Like if you load `vfio-pci` in the initramfs but not `radeon`, you don't need the softdep. If you load both `vfio-pci` and `radeon` in the initramfs OR both NOT in the initramfs, you probably need the softdep.

For example:

/etc/modules-load.d/vfio-pci.conf:

```
vfio-pci
```

/etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf:

```
softdep radeon pre: vfio-pci
```

/etc/modprobe.d/vfio-pci.conf:

```
options vfio-pci ids=XXXX:XXXX
```

The "ids" can be checked by `lspci -nn`. You may want to add the id of the HDMI Audio device of that card as well. The list is comma-separated (i.e. ids=XXXX:XXXX,YYYY:YYYY)

Btw, as long as you've done this correctly, you don't need to manually re-bind driver with sysfs/echo afterwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. I will try this tomorrow!